# What is the location of Encache search API code base? Is it OpenSource?

Tags: java, caching, search, ehcache

I have been looking over the internet to find the the source code repository as available for Ehcache Core on Github, but was unable to find.

I am looking to modify some files and send across patch request for supporting BigDecimal and BigInteger Attribute in Ehcache Search.

The package, I am looking for is `net.sf.ehcache.search.*`, is it proprietary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search API is an Ehcache 2.x feature. The source code for that version is in Subversion, hosted at http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/ehcache/trunk/ehcache/

If you intend to provide patches, you should first file an issue at https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC/ which is the issue tracker for Ehcache 2.x.

Comment: Thanks @LouisJacomet, Will there be no inclusion of search API in Ehcache 3.x?

If I need to upgrade my application to use Ehcache 3.x in future, what will be the required steps since we are also using Ehcache 2.x search API?

Comment: I have created an issue, its Jira id is [EHC-1126](https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC-1126)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK The package that you are looking for is not available in ehcache 3.x. Maybe your contribution will be useful in 3.x line but you have to find new way of implementing this (if it is not there already). Contribution guide is [here](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/wiki).

Source of ehcache 2.x is available to download from: http://www.ehcache.org/downloads/ ([current version here](http://d2zwv9pap9ylyd.cloudfront.net/ehcache-2.10.1-distribution.tar.gz)) but i beleive there is no contribution guide to this line.